# Ionic Unable to pass storage as a dependancy without getting "Illegal Constructor" error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I just upgraded my Ionic app (3.9.2 & Angular 5). I'm getting an "illegal" constructor error because I'm trying to use storage with angular-jwt in app.module.

Is there another way of doing this? I need to make sure that tokenGetter retrieves the token so that it is sent along with every HTTP request.

app.module.ts

```
// Passing storage 
export function jwtOptionsFactory(storage) {
  return {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return storage.get('token');
    },
    whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:8080']
  }
}

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
    }),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      jwtOptionsProvider: {
        provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: jwtOptionsFactory,
        deps: [Storage] // Storage is a dependancy 
      }
    })
  ],

  providers: [
  .........
  Storage // I need to use Storage so I have to add it as a provider
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add it as a provider....just import it.

```
      import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
```

Provided you already installed storage using the below command:

```
 npm install --save @ionic/storage
```

Comment: I need to pass it as a `dependancy` if I don't include it as a provider I get an error saying that no provider exists for Storage